Chart.js does not respect min and max values for yAxis
I have a bar chart (chart.js v4.4.2) which shows 4 different datasets. At the beginning there is no data and no Labels. There is a dataset in the background with data about the temperature, the utilization, network and the amount of users to a specific time (label).
The user can decides to which time they want to get the data. If the user wants the data to time1 = 4 and time2 = 7, I have to show the data between time 4 and 10. An algorithm provides the chart with the new label [4,5,6,7] and the dataset. When I update the chart, the declared min and max value for the yAxis are ignored. Before the update, the chart respects all min and max values for the yAxis. But I have to show the min and max value, even if the data not hit that value. It works completely fine on line charts


const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Temperatur",
        data: [20, 25, 22, 28, 500, 26, 24],
        yAxisID: "temp",
        borderColor: "lightblue",
        backgroundColor: "lightblue"
      },
      {
        label: "Auslastung",
        data: [0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.75, 2.3, 0.85, 0.8],
        yAxisID: "util",
        borderColor: "lightgreen",
        backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
      },
      {
        label: "Netzwerk",
        data: [800, 900, 1000, 850, 1600, 900, 950],
        yAxisID: "net",
        borderColor: "pink",
        backgroundColor: "pink"
      },
      {
        label: "Nutzerzahlen",
        data: [100, 120, 110, 130, 300, 125, 130],
        yAxisID: "user",
        borderColor: "orange",
        backgroundColor: "orange"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: {duration: 0},
    color: "black",
    scales:{
      temp: { position: "left" , backgroundColor: "lightblue", min: 0, max: 120},
      util: {position: "left" , backgroundColor: "lightgreen", min: 0, max: 1},
      net: {position: "right", backgroundColor: "pink", min: 0, max: 1000},
      user: {position: "right", backgroundColor: "orange", min:0}
    }
  }
});
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.2"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>



tried to add stepsize like kind of force to respect max value. But did not work. Looks like after the update the chart ignores everything with scaling besides colors and so on.

What exactly do you mean by the minimum and maximum values are not correct? I provided example data for your code, and after making it executable, everything seems to be working fine so far. Could you modify the question and provide a dataset where the error can be reproduced? (In the case of three values, there is a maximum value, but for the fourth, there isn't. For the three values, I intentionally set high numbers for May.)
